# android Intent Selector

Tags: android, android-intent

I am going through the API of the Intent class in Android, and I find a method called [setSelector()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setSelector%28android.content.Intent%29).

From its description, I get the idea that in addition to the actual intent, a second level intent is added. Also, instead of the actual intent, the selector intent will be used for finding entities who can handle it.

I am finding it hard to follow the browser example they have given. Can anyone give a simpler example of why the selector is useful ?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does an "Intent Selector" exists, what is it used for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24742393/why-does-an-intent-selector-exists-what-is-it-used-for)