# Android - Using URI permissions with broadcast

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I am trying to test whether URI permissions work with Broadcast.

The first app I have has the following code in an activity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.testintent.app.bcast");
intent.setData(contentUri);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

sendBroadcast(intent);
```

The content URI is obtained from a FileProvider.

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.android.provider.DataSharing"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/paths" />
</provider>

 contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),
                    "com.android.provider.DataSharing", /* file's path */);

 // file's path is correct - I have tested it with activity
```

In the app receiving the broadcast :

```
<receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.testintent.app.bcast" />
        </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

The receiver code - onReceive() :

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Bcast - received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Uri uri = intent.getData();

if(uri != null) {

      try {

          InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

      } 
      catch (Exception e) {

            Log.d("TEST", "Bcast - exception : " + e);
      }
 }
```

When I pass the URI as null from the first app, the broadcast reaches the receiver and I can see the toast message. However, when the URI is not null, my receiver does not even receive the broadcast.

Can anyone point out the reason for this behavior ?

**Edit** :

I edited the Receiver :

```
<receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.teachintent.app.bcast1" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
        </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

I added the `mime type`. I did this based on the rule (see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html))

```
An intent that contains both a URI and a MIME type (either explicit or 
inferable from the URI) passes the MIME type part of the test only if 
that type matches a type listed in the filter. It passes the URI 
part of the test either if its URI matches a URI in the filter or if 
it has a content: or file: URI and the filter does not specify a URI. 
In other words, a component is presumed to support content: and file: 
data if its filter lists only a MIME type.
```

Now I get the exception in the receiver :

```
D/TEST﹕ Bcast - exception : java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: 
opening provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider from 
ProcessRecord{529a7b60 1593:com.android.testintent.app/u0a55} 
(pid=1593, uid=10055) that is not exported from uid 10059
```

If I try to export the FileProvider, Android throws an exception saying Providers are not allowed to be exported.

What can I do to resolve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you are not matching the `<intent-filter>`. Your `<intent-filter>` is only matching on the action string. You also need to qualify for your `Uri`, via a `<data>` element indicating that you support <strike>the `content` scheme</strike> the right MIME type.

Comment: I've tried your approach. Actually, from my knowledge, `content` schemes are not allowed to be specified to in intent filter. One needs to specify the mime type. I specified that and I can receive the intent in the receiver, but then I get a different exception. I am posting an edit. Could you please take a look, thanks !

Comment: @Jake: I apologize for my error and have updated my answer. With respect to the `SecurityException`, that feels like the one you get when you leave off the `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` bit. That, in turn, would suggest that not all `Intent` uses honor that flag, which would be annoying. Try commenting out your `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` and see if the error is the same. If it is, then the flag doesn't work for broadcasts, apparently, or there's a bug in how you're applying it.

Comment: The first code snippet shows how I am applying that flag.

Comment: Although totally unrelated, I have a question at : http://stackoverflow.com/q/24742393/682869, that hasn't received a good answer for some time. I would really appreciate if you could spare a few minutes of your time to look at it. It is related to Android's design decision for Intent.setSelector() API. Thank you.

Comment: @Jake: I haven't come up with an intelligible use case for `setSelector()`, sorry.

Comment: were u able to figure out if FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION works with broadcasts?

Comment: @prostock: I have never had a need for that flag with a broadcast, so I did not research this further.

Comment: @CommnsWare, thx.. i just tried removing the flag from the intent, but now the broadcast is no longer received.  if i leave the flag in then i get the same  SecurityException that Jake is is getting.  Just wondering if it is possible to send the a content uri throuhgh broadcast

Comment: @prostock: "but now the broadcast is no longer received" -- if this is an implicit `Intent`, the receiver's `Intent` filter would need to be set up with `<data>` elements necessary to recognize that `Uri` (e.g., at least the `content` scheme), as I mentioned in the answer. Beyond that, I suggest that you ask your own question, where you can provide a [mcve] showing your current code and pointing out these results.